# ActionListener can't contain loops inside it

Tags: java, loops, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm programming a game in Java using Jframe. I noticed something when I wanted to use the Action Listener, especifically ActionPerformed.

```
  private void colocarBoton1() {
    boton = new JButton("Play");
    boton.setBounds(180,120,200,40);
    boton.setFont(new Font("arial", 0, 12));
    panel.add(boton);

    
    ActionListener o = new ActionListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            StateIniciarJuego a = new StateIniciarJuego();
        }
    };
    
    boton.addActionListener(o);
}
```

The class StateInciarJuego will initialize a new Jframe window, obviously using a while loop.

```
public StateIniciarJuego(){
    iniciarJuego();
}

public static void iniciarJuego() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Â¿Estas listo?");
    JFrame ventana=new JFrame("");
    Juego jueguito=new Juego();
    ventana.add(jueguito);
    ventana.setSize(1300,400);
    ventana.setLocation(70,200);
    ventana.setVisible(true);
    ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    while(true){
        if(jueguito.juegoFinalizado){
            reiniciaJuego=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Haz Perdido, Â¿Quieres Jugar de Nuevo?","Haz Perdido",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(reiniciaJuego==0){
                reiniciaValores(); 
            }else if(reiniciaJuego==1){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        
        }else{
            jueguito.repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            if(Juego.pierdeVida==true){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cuidado!!!");
                Juego.pierdeVida=false;
                Juego.vidas--;
                Auto.y_inicial=270;
                Auto.saltando=false;
                Obstaculo.x_inicial=1300;
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

This class will initialize the game, but if I call it from the ActionPerformed, the game will not load. On the other hand, if I call the class "StateIniciarJuego" from the main, or from other place. The game loads perfectly. Anyone here know why the ActionPermormed can't deal with loops?. Because if I delete the while loop from the function IniciarJuego, it works, but the game will just stay like an image and it won't move cause the while loop is neccesary

Comment: actionPerformed can handle loops just fine. Have you debugged your code?

Comment: Yes, I already did and I noticed that if the method wouldn't contain the loop, it would work, but of couse the while looop is needed because the game needs to be repainted

Comment: `System.exit(0);` - this is the only way out of the loop

Comment: @RodrigoSantisteban "_because the game needs to be repainted_". This should not be done in an infinite loop in an `ActionListener`. Swing is event driven, and you are blocking the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) if you put your game loop into the Action Listener. Therefore you will never see any GUI updates. Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and [javax.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). You will have to decouple your game loop from the main thread.